# Django model error abstract or not installed?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `python manage.py syncdb` command

**CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
sms.message: 'originator' has a relation with model `<class 'sms.models.message.Originator'>`, which has either not been installed or is abstract.**

**models.py**

```
class Originator(models.Model):
    originator_name = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='originators')


class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(help_text=_(u'The body of the message.'))
    recipient_number = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    sender = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='sent_sms_messages')
    originator = models.ForeignKey(Originator,
                                   related_name='Messages')
```

I don't see an issue tho! Can anyone else?

What I did notice is that when I remove the FK in Message to Originator the tables are created bar Originator which never gets created!

This is the model I'm adding to....

https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-sms-gateway/src/13b68d23f3a28c7d147c4a501965e2ad07f89cf7/sms/models/message.py?at=default

Maybe something else going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It installed when I added....

```
class Meta:
        app_label = 'sms'
```

To the Originator class

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `User` is the auth.User model there? It seems to be referring to the Originator model itself, which is strange.

You should probably do the same as you do in `Message`, and just use the string `auth.User` as the target of the `Originator.user` FK.

Comment: try that, Originator table just never gets created!I'm adding to this model...  https://bitbucket.org/schinckel/django-sms-gateway/src/13b68d23f3a28c7d147c4a501965e2ad07f89cf7/sms/models/message.py?at=default